# Problem with Array Modifier - Rotation

Tags: modifiers

I am trying to apply an array modifier. It is an object offset modifier for rotation around an empty. Watch this video. What am I doing wrong and I get these hick ups in the modifier?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lxH7V-w-QaA&vq=1080p

Please increase in the video the resolution if it is low by default.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please provide some context and explanation by verbally describing your issue, don't just post, images, videos, files to download, or links to external sites. See [What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “*How do I do this?*”](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Hello hard to understand what's your problem, maybe share the file with the problem once it is visible

Comment: and honestly - instead of adding music to that video you would have better improved your question and told us all the steps you did and what you mean with "hick ups".

Comment: Before trying anything else, Ctrl-A apply the (object-level) scale of your arrayed object. The object-offset mechanism iterates the transform between modified and target objects, once for each element, so it will be doing that to the scale, too.

Comment: Ok, you are correct all of you about not mentioning everything and adding music.
Here is a video where I tell everything.
https://youtu.be/AO3YfGPUSf4

Answer (score 0):

I figured that out. We have to apply Ctrl+A and then from the menu "All Transformations".